# Build Ascii Art Diagram

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a question about creating ASCII graphics in BASH.

I have a file which contains:

```
April = 90
October = 80
```

Is there some method to create a diagram using ASCII art
like this:

```
April
    [=========================] 90

October
    [================] 80
```

Comment: This would be a good use-case for a Perl script

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar in perl

Comment: Are you familiar with bash? Or something else? What have you tried so far? It seems like a simple `for` loop might get you most of the way to what you want...

Comment: Yes I am familiar in bash, but never used Pearl

Comment: That's nice, but I didn't ask you about `perl`. I asked you how you have tried to solve this using `bash`.

Comment: Search for "ascii bar chart in shel" over the Internet... Lots of solutions

Comment: For several methods, see [Drawing an histogram from a bash command output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177777/drawing-an-histogram-from-a-bash-command-output).

Comment: @agc Thank you for your reply this very useful example for that.

Comment: @jean-baptiste-yun I searched such topic, but for now just simple lines in diagram more easy, anyway thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bash` a possible solution is to use `printf` combined with `seq` to print a sequence of numbers converted in zero-length strings followed by a fixed char (in this case `=`):

```
printf "%.0s=" $(seq 1 5) # output -> =====
```

Explanation:

- `seq 1 5`: it just prints a sequence of space-separated integers from `1` to `5` (i.e., `1 2 3 4 5`)

Incremental explanation of the `printf` format string `%.0s=`:

- `%s`: format each following printf argument (i.e. the numerical sequence) as a string;
- `%.0s`: the added dot followed by an integer (in this case `.0`) means omit this string if it is greater than the number. So in this case with `0` it means **always omit** the string. The form `%.s` is a shorter equivalent version of the zero previous one;
- `%.s=`: we added a `=` to make the string (omitted) being followed by a fixed char (in this case `=`).

So basically to accomplish your task you have to parse the input line by line with a loop to obtain the actual `month` and the `lenght` of the bar, store them into variables and then to print the bar you can use something like that:

```
echo "${month}"
echo "    [$(printf "%.s=" $(seq 1 ${length}))]"
```

With an example result of:

> April
>         [====================]